# Интерпретатор Clojure. Не перемещается курсор при редактировании

Tags: ubuntu, интерпретатор, clojure

В интерпретаторе *Clojure* отображается символ `^[[D` при перемещении курсора влево.

Установлена *Ubuntu 14, Clojure 1.7*

*readline* установлена.

Как исправить такую реакцию на перемещение курсора?

Comment: *readline установлена* — проверьте, используется ли эта библиотека интерпретатором для взаимодействия с пользователем.

Comment: Какой командой вы запустили интерпретатор?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

судя по всему, интерпретатор *clojure* **не** использует *readline*.

поэтому для использования возможностей *readline*-а надо запускать интерпретатор через «обёртку» `rlwrap`.

к примеру, если вы запускаете интерпретатор как `java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main` (увидел эту команду [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7657016/4827341)), то «через обёртку» можно запустить её так:

```
$ rlwrap java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main
```

но, чтобы пользоваться было удобно, [здесь](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Getting_Started#Enhancing_Clojure_REPL_with_rlwrap) рекомендуют использовать ещё опции `-r` и `-c` (см. их описание в `man rlwrap`):

```
$ rlwrap -r -c java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main
```

а чтобы не вводить (или не искать в истории *shell*-а) эту команду каждый раз, можно создать *alias* по имени, например, `clj`:

```
$ alias clj='rlwrap -r -c java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main'
```

и эту последнюю команду добавить, например, в конец файла `~/.bashrc`, а после этого запускать интерпретатор короткой командой:

```
$ clj
```